# Rails 3, Passing date params to url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a search action in my controller that looks like this...

```
def search
@from_date = Date.new(params[:from_date][:year].to_i, params[:from_date][:month].to_i, params[:from_date][:day].to_i).to_s(:db)
@to_date = Date.new(params[:to_date][:year].to_i, params[:to_date][:month].to_i, params[:to_date][:day].to_i).to_s(:db)
@visits = Visit.search(from_date, to_date, current_user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
```

end

This works fine if I call this action from from this view..

```
<% form_tag "visits/search" do %>
<p/>
<%= 'Enter the dates to print' %>
<p/>
<%= select_date(Date.current, :order => [:month, :day, :year],     :prefix=>'from_date')     %>
- to-
<%= select_date(Date.current, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :prefix => 'to_date') %>
<%= submit_tag "Show me Visits" %>
<% end %>
```

However, I am trying to create a pdf with this view, so I need to pass the from_date and to_date into the url. To do this I am using a link_to statement...

```
<p><%= link_to "Print PDF", visits_search_path(format: 'pdf', from_date: @from_date, to_date: @to_date) %></p>
```

This gives me a nicely formed url that looks like...

```
/visits/search.pdf?from_date=2011-09-22&to_date=2012-02-22
```

but when I click this link, I get the error..

```
TypeError in VisitsController#search

can't convert Symbol into Integer

Rails.root: /home/jlocklear/railsApps/ezslp_w_prawn
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/visits_controller.rb:104:in `[]'
app/controllers/visits_controller.rb:104:in `search'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I need to build the correct params in my link_to statement. Rather using something like

> visits_search_path(format: 'pdf', from_date: @from_date, to_date: @to_date)

I really needed something more akin to...

> visits_search_path('from_date[year]' => @from_date.year, 'from_date[month]' => @from_date.month, ... )

My solution ended up being to use the params.merge method as in...

```
  <p><%= link_to "Print PDF", visits_search_path(params.merge(format: 'pdf')) %></p>
```

..which auto-magically inserts the params from the controller into my url.